# Other factors of the equation $2x^4 + 4x^3\sin A\sin B -\cdots$

Tags: quadratics

If $x^2+x\cos(A + B) + 1$ is a factor of the expression,
$$2x^4 + 4x^3\sin A\sin B -x^2(\cos 2A +\cos 2B) + 4x\cos A\cos B -2$$
Then we have to find the other factor (s).

I am not getting start

Can anybody provide me a hint .

Comment: Perform long division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prerequisites**: Recall the identities: $$2\sin A\sin B = \cos (A-B) -\cos (A+B) \tag {1} $$ $$2\cos A \cos B = \cos (A+B) + \cos (A-B) \tag {2} $$

Using these, our expression simplifies to $$2x^4 +2x^3\cos (A-B) -2x^3\cos (A+B) -2x^2\cos (A+B)\cos (A-B) +2x\cos(A+B)+ 2x\cos (A-B)-2$$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: @user123733 Performing long division will now be very easy to clean things up.

Answer (score 1):

Then the other factor shall be a quadratic polynomial
that can be generally formulated as
$$
C\,x^{\,2}  + D\,x + E
$$
So you must have
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {C\,x^{\,2}  + D\, x + E} \right)\left( {\,x^{\,2}  + \,\cos (A + B)\,x + 1} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = 2x^{\,4}  + \left( {4\sin A\sin B} \right)\,x^{\,3}  - \left( {\cos 2A + \cos 2B} \right)x^{\,2}  + \left( {4\cos A\cos B} \right)\,x - 2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and equating the coefficients of the powers of x
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  C = 2 \hfill \\
  C\cos (A + B) + D = 4\sin A\sin B \hfill \\
  C + D\cos \left( {A + B} \right) + E =  - \left( {\cos 2A + \cos 2B} \right) \hfill \\
  D + E\cos (A + B) = 4\cos A\cos B \hfill \\
  E =  - 2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
Now, adding 2nd row+4th row gives:
$$
D = 2\left( {\cos A\cos B + \sin A\sin B} \right) = 2\cos (A - B)
$$
However, this does not satisfy any of the three middle row !
That means that 
$\left( {\,x^{\,2}  + \,\cos (A + B)\,x + 1} \right)$ is not a factor of the quartic binomial, for any generic $A$ and $B$.
Substituting $D =  2\cos (A - B)$ back into the system, you get that it is totally satisfied iff
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \cos (A + B) = 0 \hfill \\
  \cos (2A) + \cos (2B) = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
i.e., if
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  A + B = \pi /2 + 2k\pi  \hfill \\
  2A = 2B + \pi  + 2j\pi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  A + B = \pi /2 + 2k\pi  \hfill \\
  A - B = \pi /2 + j\pi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  A = \left( {2k + j + 1} \right)\pi /2 \hfill \\
  B = \left( {2k - j} \right)\pi /2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$